# I am trying to debug my javascript, but whenever i am clicking on play paused button, Grammerly.js starts debug

Tags: javascript, debugging

I am trying to debug my javascript, but whenever I am clicking on play paused button, Grammerly.js starts to debug.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try hitting `deactive breakpoints`. It looks like this -

[image]

If that doesn't work, disable grammerly.

Comment: I need to use break points. and i already disabled grammerly.

Comment: @Sunny if you remove grammerly does it still happen?

Comment: If you have `removed` grammerly from chrome I am unsure why it would still be debugging in the console. But if you click through to the next breakpoint grammerly would run since it checks text input.